# How do I best implement this massive query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, database-design

So I have tables like

```
--                  Partners 
-- ============================================================
--   id  | name                  | email
-- ============================================================
--    1  | 'Haliburton'          | 'DCheney@Haliburton.org'
--    2  | 'Berkshire Hathaway'  | 'WarrenBridgemaster@bershire.org'
--    3  | 'Jason'               | 'jason89@gmail.com'


--                Sections
-- =========================================
--   id  |          title              
-- =========================================
--    1  |  'Partner planning'         
--    2  |  'Partner prospecting'   
--    3  |  'Partner recruiting'          
--    4  |  'Partner activation'     
--    5  |  'Partner growth'   


--             Subsections
-- ==============================================
--   id  |       title             | section_id
-- ==============================================
--    1  | 'Target Markets'        |    1
--    2  | 'Target Customers'      |    1
--    3  | 'Competition'           |    1
--    4  | 'Partner Profile'       |    2
--    5  | 'Partner value'         |    3
--    6  | 'Partner Qualification' |    3
--    7  | 'Business Terms'        |    4
--    8  | 'Getting Traction'      |    5


--                                            Questions
-- ====================================================================================================================
--   id  |                        qtext                                                               |  subsection_id
-- ====================================================================================================================
--    1  | 'Have you defined the target markets in terms of industries, verticals and subverticals?'  |   1
--    2  | 'Have you identified the number of potential customers in each state or region?'           |   1
--    3  | 'Have you built a market coverage model estimating the number of partners in each region?' |   1
--    4  | 'Have you built the revenue model to estimate sales by partners in each region?'           |   1
--    5  | 'Have you built a market coverage model estimating the number of partners in each region?' |   2
--    .                                           .                                                       .
--    .                                           .                                                       .
--    .                                           .                                                       .
--    .                                           .                                                       .
--    .                                           .                                                       .
--    61 | 'Have you defined the customer references acquisition process?'                             |  8


--                   Answers
-- =========================================
--   id  |  question_id | partner_id | val
-- =========================================
--    1  |      1       |     1      | 24
--    2  |      2       |     1      | 50
--    3         1       |     2      | 0
--    4  |      3       |     1      | 90
```

where the associations are self-explanatory (`section_id` in `Subsections` refers to `id` in `Sections`, `partner_id` in `Answers` refers to `id` in `Partners`, etc.).

What I'm trying to do is write a sproc that, for a given `Partner.id`, returns rows for each question the partner has answered, with `NULL` for answer value and answer id for any questions they haven't answered, along with the text of the question, the id of the anw the id of the question, the title of the sections and subsections.

**Question 1:** Since the

```
-- =============================================================================================
--   section_title     |  subsection_title  |  question_id |            question_text           
-- =============================================================================================
--  'Partner Planning' | 'Target Markets'   |       1      | 'Have you defined the target ...?'  
--  'Partner Planning' | 'Target Markets'   |       2      | 'Have you identified the .......?' 
--  'Partner Planning' | 'Target Markets'   |       3      | 'Have you built a market .......?'  
--  'Partner Planning' | 'Target Markets'   |       4      | 'Have you built the revenue ....?'  
--  'Partner Planning' | 'Target Customers' |       5      | 'Have you defined the ideal ....?' 
--          .                   .                   .                         .                 
--          .                   .                   .                         .                  
--          .                   .                   .                         .                 
--          .                   .                   .                         .                
--  'Partner Growth'   | 'Getting Traction' |       61      | 'Have you defined the ideal ....?'
```

portion of the table returned by the sproc will be the same every time the sproc is called, should I make a separate sproc that returns that table? Why or why not?

*EDIT:*
**Question 2:** Is the following correct for the entire query?

```
BEGIN
    SELECT Sections.title AS section_title,
           Subsections.title AS subsection_title,
           Questions.id AS question_id,
           Questions.qtext AS question_text,
           Answers.id AS answer_id,
           Answers.val AS answer_val
    FROM 
    Answers RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( 
        SELECT *
        FROM Questions INNER JOIN (
            SELECT *
            FROM Subsections INNER JOIN Sections
            ON Subsections.section_id = Sections.id
        )
        ON Questions.id = Answers.question_id
    )                              
    ON  Question.id = Answers.question_id
    WHERE Answers.partner_id = @pid
END
```

???

As you can tell, I'm a n00b to database programming.

Comment: Your left join in Q2 needs a condition to only return the answers for a specific partner, otherwise you'll get all answers to the question, no matter the partner. Besides that, looks ok at a quick glance, but of course testing may find other anomalies.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do the trick, start with a list of all your partners. The INNER JOIN to questions on a condition that is always met will return every question for every partner. You can then LEFT JOIN out to Answers based on the partner Id with an added clause to filter the specific question_id

```
    SELECT Sections.title AS section_title,
       Subsections.title AS subsection_title,
       Questions.id AS question_id,
       Questions.qtext AS question_text,
       Answers.id AS answer_id,
       Answers.val AS answer_val 
    FROM Partner
    INNER JOIN Questions on 1 = 1
    INNER JOIN Subsections on Subsections.Id = Questions.subsection_id
    INNER JOIN Sections on Sections.Id = Subsections.section_id
    LEFT JOIN Answers on Answers.partner_id = Partner.Id
            AND Answers.questions_id = Questions.Id
    WHERE Partner.Id = @pid
```

The initial query you posted would work, but this just looks a little cleaner.